# MacBook Pro still has a distinctive smell — what is it?

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013), and when I open it up, I still notice a certain smell, which I associate with the aluminum somehow. I wouldn't describe it as the same as the [new Mac smell](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/1x322c/apple_product_smell/) which gets so much press. What could be the source of the smell? Aluminum in itself does not have an odour.

Comment: Do you use the MacBook in a special environment (e.g. extreme temperatures)

Comment: Nope, nothing unusual in the environment. Mix of work and home, basic business environment.

Comment: Well I can't go over there and smell your computer, but my own computer can produce a smell that reminds me of burning plastic if the processor is doing too much for too long and getting too hot (it can near 200F). Other times I can still smell something that I notise a lot if I put my nose above a warm computer screen or iMac. Just something from the internals, maybe glue I don't know, getting warm. Does yours have the same smell when it's off?

Comment: I can't remember where this came from, but someone mentioned to me that it might be the smell of ozone.